# confusion in saturation concept

Tags: networking, router

I am a bit confused in understanding the concept of saturation.. and difference between saturation and congestion ..

I read somewhere (definition of saturation)

"A saturated network link is a link that should transmit more frames than is possible on its physical support. These include, for example, the port of a router should send 110 Mbps (megabits per second) when the standard used is the 100BaseTX (100 Mbps).

At this point the router starts by placing the packets supernumerary in a local buffer."

But I really cant understand how can a link with 100Mbps capacity can take 110 Mbps or just more than its capacity and why does not the queue before link drop the packets if its full ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saturation is ratio of utilization to capacity, while congestion is the state of being over-saturated.

- A 100Mbps line sending 50Mbps of data is 50% saturated and not congested
- A 100Mbps line sending 100Mbps of data is 100% or completely saturated (but not yet congested)
- A 100Mbps line trying to send 110Mbps of data is over-saturated and congested, resulting in 10Mbps of data filling up the send buffers and then being discarded if the buffers become full.